# Deploying Node Js application with express framework in Supabase (Edge Functions)

Tags: node.js, express, supabase

I developed a node Js application integrated with some **services like database, authentication from Supabase**, It works fine and gave success results in local development for each routes when called from Postman. Now **I want to deploy this application to make rest APIs for frontend**. Supabase provides **edge-functions**. In their documentation they told it is an alternative for firebase functions. But I can't able to find any documentation or blog regarding deployment of node Js application. Is there any way to **deploy this application like firebase functions** on edge functions of Supabase **Any clarification related docs or alternative solutions would be helpful**.

Answer (score 2):

Supabase edge functions run Deno application at the moment, which is a bit different from a node.js application, so your node.js application will not deploy directly to Supabase edge functions. You would have to rewrite your code to make it compatible with a Deno application.

Luckily, since typescript, the language used in Deno functions is a superset of javascript, so you should be able to reuse a lot of the code during the rewrite!

Comment: Language-wise - yes. Dependency-wise - it's a mess.

Comment: That's why it's paramount to write adapters around the vendor-lock platforms that we use  – I feel you... Try to refactor in many small iterations and refactor all the dependencies from Node into small functions inside a single `platform.js` file, and then replace their use all around the codebase (search&replace will help you a lot). After that, you can refactor the `platform.js` to make use of Deno instead of Node. And make use of import-map to alias the imported dependencies and make them easier to use.